# Full list of Status values on the LoginHistory object

Tags: apex

As per the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_loginhistory.htm), 'Status' field on the sObject LoginHistory is a string.

The different values I have come across for this field so far are:

1   Success

2   Failed: Computer activation required

3   Failed: API security token required

4   Failed: Mobile License Required

5   Password Lockout

6   User is Inactive

7   Invalid Password

Are there any others? Is there a link where we can see the most up to date values?

Comment: I know there's at least a few related to SAML authentication errors (e.g. incorrect computer time, incorrect signature, etc), but I can't seem to find an example of them right now. Delegated Authentication can also fail with unique status messages, but I don't have an easy way of configuring that to test, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no documentation on all of the available values (please feel free to edit this if there is indeed such documentation).

This community wiki is free for editing by anyone that has observed different values.

The known values are:

- Success
- Failed: Computer activation required
- Failed: API security token required
- Failed: Mobile License Required
- Password Lockout
- User is Inactive
- Invalid Password
- User Is Frozen